# Line break inside \title

Tags: titles, article

This is template for the abstract as we received it from the org.committee. I cannot make line break in the title. I am very grateful in advance for help.

```
\documentclass[A4,10pt]{article}
\setlength\parindent{12pt}
\setlength\textwidth{30pc}
\setlength\textheight{48pc}%45 eil.
\advance\textheight by\topskip
\def\title#1{\centerline{\LARGE\bf #1}\vskip .5em}
\def\author#1{\noindent{#1}\vskip .5em}
\def\address#1{\noindent{\it #1}\vskip .5em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,eucal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\title{Markov-Modulated Linear Regression for Incomplete Observations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This "template" has all the appearance of being something of a hack. The problem is with `\centerline` (often a danger signal!) (as is `\bf`)

What about

```
\def\title#1{\begingroup
 \centering\LARGE\bfseries #1\par
 \vskip .5em%
 \endgroup}
```

This will allow the line to break "naturally", or by means of manual linebreaks (which a solution using `longstack` doesn't: it requires manual breaking, not that it probably matters much here).

(But of course it's often unacceptable to alter anything in a template, in which case the only real solution is to shorten your title!)

Answer (score 2):

Incorporating a `\Longstack` into the definition of `\title` will now allow `\\` style linebreaks.

```
\documentclass[A4,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setlength\parindent{12pt}
\setlength\textwidth{30pc}
\setlength\textheight{48pc}%45 eil.
\advance\textheight by\topskip
\def\title#1{\centerline{\LARGE\bf\Longstack{#1}}\vskip .5em}
\def\author#1{\noindent{#1}\vskip .5em}
\def\address#1{\noindent{\it #1}\vskip .5em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,eucal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\title{Markov-Modulated Linear Regression\\for Incomplete Observations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No joy.  `Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: @guero64 Sounds like you don't have the `stackengine` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Answer (score 1):

```
\maketitle{First Line of Title \\ $\ $ \\ Second Line of Title}
```